# Extjs store: implement 'find()' in reverse direction

Tags: extjs, store, extjs4.2

So the Extjs 4.0 has various methods to find a particular value in a particular field. From the docs:

```
find( fieldName, value, [startIndex], [anyMatch], [caseSensitive], [exactMatch] )
```

works perfectly.

What I want to do is to implement the same thing in reverse direction. for example, if the `startIndex` is 100, I want to test records 99, 98, 97 and so on until I find a hit. However, I can't find any way to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: "I can't find any way to do that." What exactly have you tried? What are you having trouble figuring out?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source, you'll see that `find` simply calls the method `findIndexBy` on the MixedCollection:

```
// store:
find: function(property, value, start, anyMatch, caseSensitive, exactMatch) {
    var fn = this.createFilterFn(property, value, anyMatch, caseSensitive, exactMatch);
    return fn ? this.data.findIndexBy(fn, null, start) : -1;
},

// mixedcollection
findIndexBy : function(fn, scope, start){
    var me = this,
        keys = me.keys,
        items = me.items,
        i = start || 0,
        len = items.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (fn.call(scope || me, items[i], keys[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
},
```

So to get your desired result you just have to create your own `find` method and change the last `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method. Probably the easiest would be to:

1. call [`getRange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) from 0 to 101
2. iterate backwards through the returned array to find the record(s)